# Physical back button not working on home screen in Flutter app with GoRouter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-go-router

Problem:

- I have a Flutter app with GoRouter navigation.
- The initial route is `/welcome`, which navigates to `/splash`, then to `/home`.
- The `/home` page has several tabs for different sections: `/explore`, `/dialogs`, `/notifications`, and `/settings`.
- Navigating to `/profile` from any tab works, and I can back to the previous screen using the physical back button.
- However, the physical back button does not work on the `home screen` (from any tab).

Desired behavior:

- I want the app to close (not just kill) when the user presses the physical back button on the `home screen` (from any tab).

The code:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> parentNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'parent');
   
  final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
   debugLogDiagnostics: true,
   navigatorKey: parentNavigatorKey,
   initialLocation: appManager.isFreshUser ? RoutePaths.welcome : RoutePaths.splash,
   routes: [
    GoRoute(
     path: RoutePaths.welcome,
     parentNavigatorKey: parentNavigatorKey,
     builder: (context, state) => const WelcomeScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
     path: RoutePaths.splash,
     parentNavigatorKey: parentNavigatorKey,
     builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
    ),
    ShellRoute(
     navigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
     builder: (context, state, child) {
      return HomeScreen();
     },
     routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
       path: RoutePaths.explore,
       parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
       pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
        child: ExploreScreen(),
       ),
      ),
      GoRoute(
       path: RoutePaths.dialogs,
       parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
       pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const DialogsScreen(),
       ),
      ),
      GoRoute(
       path: RoutePaths.notifications,
       parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
       pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const NotificationsScreen(),
       ),
      ),
      GoRoute(
       path: RoutePaths.settings,
       parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
       pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const SettingsScreen(),
       ),
      ),
     ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
     path: RoutePaths.profile,
     parentNavigatorKey: parentNavigatorKey,
     builder: (context, state) => const ProfileScreen(),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add NavigationRouteObserver to the Go router,The RouteObserver in Flutter allows you to listen to page transition events. In cases where you need to perform some action when a page is pushed or popped, the RouteObserver can be useful.

```
static GoRouter returnRouter(bool isAuth) {
    GoRouter router = GoRouter(
      navigatorKey: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
      observers: [
        NavigationRouteObserver(),
      ],
      routes: <RouteBase>[ ]
)}

  class NavigationRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {

    @override
    void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
      print('didPop()');

      // The business logic needed on back button
    }
  }
```